# Using Django REST framework, how to avoid fetching an object in both serializer and view?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Let's say one of my POSTed DRF API params is a string that allows me to identify an object.  My serializer then uses this field to validate the string (together with some other POSTed params) and fetch the underlying object (as the final part of the validation).  So, at the end of my `validate()`, I have already looked up the object I need to work with in my view, but I can't figure out how to access this object in the view.  If I set `data['my_object'] = my_object` at the end of `validate()`, it ends up being just the name of my object after `serializer.is_valid()` returns in my view.

How do I "pass" objects from the serializer back to the view?  (Or, if there's a reason not to do that, what's the best practice to avoid looking up the same object in the database twice?)

```
# serializer
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    my_string_param = serializers.CharField()
    another_param = serializers.CharField()
    ...
    def validate(self, data):
        # validate data['my_string_param'] and fetch my_object
        try:
            my_object = MyModel.objects.get(
                field1=data['my_string_param'], field2=data['another_param'])
        except MyModel.DoesNotExist:
            raise ValidationError('Please check your params and try again.')
        data['my_object'] = my_object  # doesn't work: is a string when later accessed in the view 
        return data

# view
class MyView(APIView):
    ...
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = MySerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            # don't want to fetch from db again
            # my_object = MyModel.objects.get(field1=serializer.data['my_string_param'], field2=serializer.data['another_param'])

            # would like to reuse already fetched object, but it's just its str name
            my_object = serializer.data['my_object']

            # do stuff with my_object and return
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Please add your view also.

Comment: Why the downvote?  The DRF docs don't answer this and there are no similar questions on SO.  Whoever downvoted, please comment.

Comment: Just going to add a new question on this and found this question. Django community is great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **set the fetched object as a serializer attribute** and then access this attribute in your view. Doing this will  avoid an extra query in your view.

```
# serializer
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    my_string_param = serializers.CharField()
    another_param = serializers.CharField()
    ...
    def validate(self, data):
        # validate data['my_string_param'] and fetch my_object
        try:
            # set the object as an attribute
            self.my_object = MyModel.objects.get( 
                field1=data['my_string_param'], field2=data['another_param'])
        except MyModel.DoesNotExist:
            raise ValidationError('Please check your params and try again.')
        return data

# view
class MyView(APIView):
    ...
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = MySerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():            
            my_object = serializer.my_object # access the already retrieved object 

            # do stuff with my_object and return
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Looks like this works, thank you.  Is this a good practice though?  Seems like a bit of a hack--do you know if this is "DRF-approved" :) ?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot think of any other way to pass data from serializer to view. Maybe to make it more clean, you can create a function `get_my_object()` on the serializer which returns `self.my_object` if that helps. Then in your view, you can the access object by that function `serializer.get_my_object()` instead of directly accessing by `serializer.my_object`.